# pass the window using a CommandParameter from a ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, trayicon

The goal is to hide/show a window from the task tray using Hardcoded WPF `NotifyTrayIcon` in a MVVM solution. The problem is the `CommandParameter` always seems to be null, which then of course cause the code to crash.  I've tried a number of different bindings including:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"

CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=window, Mode=OneWay}"
```

etc but everything passes back a null, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the Output window to view WPF debug messages, also context menus are detached from the visual tree, refer to PlacementTarget.

Comment: Do whatever you want, because passing the window to the view model isn't MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one Window then you could simply use `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

If you have more then you may search for the good one in the `Application.Current.Windows` collection.

Comment: This didn't answer the question, but solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: @DukeNukem "the simpler the better" is a rule we often forget in IT. :)

Comment: This doesn't help me at all, and I suspect many others as well. As @DukeNukem says, it doesn't answer the question, and I still can;'t pass the current dialogue as a command parameter on the "Cancel" button's command parameter in that dialogue.